Utility function and Balanced Growth
I'm reading the article published by Acemoglu and Restrepo (AER,2018). They propose a growth model where the demand side of the economy is represented by the following utility function:
\begin{equation}
u(C, L) = \frac{\left(C e^{-\nu(L)}\right)^{1-\theta} - 1}{1-\theta}
\label{UF}
\end{equation}
where $ C $ is consumption, $ L $ denotes the labor supply of the representative household, and $ \nu(L) $ designates the utility cost of labor supply, which is assumed to be continuously differentiable, increasing, and convex, and to satisfy $ \nu''(L) + \frac{\theta - 1}{\theta} \times (\nu'(L))^2 > 0 $ (which ensures that $ u(C, L) $ is concave).
The functional form of the utility ensures balanced growth. Can you explain me why?

You can find the solution in King/Plosser/Rebelo (2002), page 94-95 at https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1020529028761
